# VB.NET Unable to add or import rows to a DataTable from a existing DataSet Table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a problem with below code where I get "object not set to an instance of an object" error on the `dt.ImportRow(cr)` line.

```
Dim DataGrid As DataTable = Me.DataSet1.MyGrid()

    For i As Integer = DataGrid.Rows.Count - 1 To -0 Step -1
        Dim dr As DataRow = DataGrid.Rows.Item(i)
        Dim new_value1 = 0
        Dim new_value2 = 0
        Dim new_value3 = 0
        Dim new_value4 = 0
        Dim new_value5 = 0

        If CheckItem(dr("WH"), dr("PC")) Then
            Dim dt As DataTable 
            For Each cr As DataRow In Me.DataSet1.MyGrid()
                If cr("parent") = dr("WH") + dr("PC") And cr("lev") = dr("lev") + 1 Then
                    dt.ImportRow(cr)

                End If
            Next
            dt.AcceptChanges()

            RemoveDuplicateRows(dt)

            For Each dr1 As DataRow In dt.Rows
                new_value1 = new_value1 + dr1("new_value1")
                new_value2 = new_value2 + dr1("new_value2")
                new_value3 = new_value3 + dr1("new_value3")
                new_value4 = new_value4 + dr1("new_value4")
                new_value5 = new_value5 + dr1("new_value1") + dr1("new_value2") + dr1("new_value3") + dr1("new_value4")
            Next

            dr("new_value1 ") = Math.Round(new_value1 , 4)
            dr("new_value2 ") = Math.Round(new_value2 , 4)
            dr("new_value3 ") = Math.Round(new_value3 , 4)
            dr("new_value4 ") = Math.Round(new_value4 , 4)
            dr("new_value5 ") = Math.Round(new_value5 , 4)
        End If

    Next
```

What I am trying to do is populate `dt` with rows which can be a duplicate within the `Me.DataSet1.MyGrid()` so that then I can execute the `RemoveDuplicateRows()` method in order to only show distinct rows and then add values up from them. The issue was that I was having duplicate values and when I was doing my adding up of values, it was duplicating the outcome, e.g. where I expected 4 I was getting 8.

Why am I not able to `Rows.Add(cr)` or `ImportRow(cr)` into the `dt` DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the line:

> Dim dt As DataTable

It needs to be extended a little bit to be:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DataGrid.Clone()
```

This will result in the new DataTable `dt` having the same columns as the original DataTable `DataGrid`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Exactly what I was missing the .Clone()... Could not figure out how to replicate the structure as I did think that was the issue. Thank you,